# Oracle nested table append

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I have an oracle nested table as follows:

```
create table test_tab
(
Col1        VARCHAR,
Col2        VARCHAR,
Col3        VARCHAR,
Col4       Coltype,
PK(col1,col2,col3)
 );
```

Coltype definition:

```
create type Coltype as varray(10) of Coltuple;
```

Coltuple definition:

```
create type remarktuple as object
(
ColX varchar,
Coly varchar,
Colz varchar
);
```

and i have inserted a single row

```
insert into test_tab values('A','B','C',Coltype(Coltuple('X','Y','Z'));
```

now, if i want to inserted `Coltype(Coltupele('P','Q','R'))` to the same A,B,C row, how can i do it??...
When i use a separate insert like `insert into test_tab values('A','B','C',Coltype(Coltuple('P','Q','R'));` , it is assuming it as a second insert and throwing error because of PK voilation.

Hope i have explained my requirement clearly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above definition, `Col4` is not a nested table; it's a varray. For `Col4` to be a nested table, first, `Coltype` should be defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE Coltype AS TABLE of Coltuple;
```

Then, `test_tab` should be defined as something like the below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab
(
Col1        VARCHAR2(30),
Col2        VARCHAR2(30),
Col3        VARCHAR2(30),
Col4        Coltype,
PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2,col3)
)
NESTED TABLE Col4 STORE AS ColtypeStoreTab;
```

Now, with `(Col1,Col2,Col3)` being defined as the primary key of the parent table, it is not possible to insert another row with the values of `('A','B','C')` while such a row already exists in the table unless the primary key constraint of the parent table is relaxed. **Much probably**, you wanted to insert `('P','Q','R')` into the nested table of the parent table's row where `(Col1,Col2,Col3)` was`('A','B','C')`. If that's the case, here is how it could be achieved:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(SELECT Col4 FROM test_tab 
                  WHERE Col1 = 'A' AND Col2 = 'B' AND  Col3 = 'C')
VALUES('P','Q','R');
```

Comment: Thank you ver much sir. Your solution has been fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is this one:

```
UPDATE test_tab 
SET Col4 = Col4 MULTISET UNION Coltype(Coltuple('P','Q','R'))
WHERE Col1 = 'A' AND Col2 = 'B' AND  Col3 = 'C';
```